# Numpy: sigma notion over two 2D arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following 2D Numpy arrays that can take an arbitrary `shape (d, c)`, with `d` and `c` being equal to each other :

```
import numpy as np
arr_a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
arr_b = np.array([[10, 20, 30], [40, 50, 60]])
```

I want to solve for `t` (a float) by taking the summation of these 2D arrays as follows:

[image]

I believe `np.add(arr_a, arr_b)` returns a matrix, so that wouldn't apply here.

Are there any native Numpy functions that can do this?  Or, would I have to iterate through `arr_a` and `arr_b`?

And, if iteration is required here, how would I apply the summation logic above to the iteration?

(part of my confusion is understanding the `i-th` and `j-th` elements)

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: The equation seems incorrect. Assuming that `c > d`, then `arr[c-1][i]` will refer to a non-existing element (*i*-th element of a non-existing row to be exact).

Comment: The equation is correct.  `0 <= i < d,  0 <= j < c`

Comment: Probably, you'll want to do some matrix operations first.  For example `A[i][j] + B[j][i]` is equivalent to `A[i][j] + B^T[i][j]`.

Comment: @equanimity I assume that the first square bracket refers to row number and the second refers to column numbers. Now let `d = 2` and `c = 3`, what does `B[2][1]` refer to? (because there are only two rows so only `B[0][x]` or `B[1][x]` is defined)

Comment: @bui - yes, `i` is the row and `j` is the column.  Yes, `B[2][1]` would be out of bounds using the toy example I provided.

Comment: So is the equation incorrect (because it may refer to out of bound elements), or the assumption that `d` and `c` are arbitrary incorrect, or that whenever `A` and `B` appears together, one is actually the transpose and one is the original?

Comment: @bui - `d` and `c` are arbitrary, but of the *same size*.  Apologies for the confusion.  I edited the original post.

Comment: If `d = c`, then `t = np.sum(A + B.T + A.T - B)`. To visualize it, you can assume a fixed `i`, says `i=0`, in which case the sum over `j` is actually the *sum of sum* of `A's` first *row* and `B's` first *column*, while the difference over `j` is the *sum of difference* of `A's` first *column* and `B`'s first *row*.

Answer (score 0):

If A and B are square matrices, equation in the picture just translates to `2*np.sum(a)`

```
import numpy as np

A = np.random.rand(100,100) ##
B = np.random.rand(100,100) ## 

your_required_answer = 2*np.sum(A) ## np.sum(A-B) + np.sum(A.T+B.T)
```